# PHP converting Chinese text to hashtag link

Tags: php, regex, multilingual

I am trying to convert user's posts (text) into hashtag clickable links, using PHP.

my code is

```
$string = 'testing text #tag1 testing text #tag2'
$ur =   $myurl;
$description=preg_replace('/#(\\w+)/','<a href='.$ur.'/$1>$0</a>',$string);
```

its work great when post is in English but its fail when user post in Chinese language

How can above work on Chinese language.

Thanks

Comment: `$description = preg_replace('/#(\p{Han}+)/u','<a href='.$ur.'/$1>$0</a>',$string);`

Comment: Thanks , but it fails when input is in English.

Comment: Then `(\p{L}+)` might be what you're looking for: https://regex101.com/r/vP1lU6/1